# How do you install jgimp?

Tags: java, plugins, gimp

How do you install jgimp as a plugin for gimp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. One of the last messages of the [JGimp mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/jgimp/mailman/jgimp-developers/) says that JGimp was designed for Gimp 1.x and the last update to the package was in May 2003, indeed well before Gimp v2.0 (March 2004). Assuming the interface still works you would still be missing a lot of the 2.x functionality.

Gimp now natively supports Python plugins (for Windows a Python interpreter is included in the package since Gimp 2.8). You can code Gimp plugins in Python, and they can have their own UI (TkInter or PyGtk).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know python :( too bad. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Neither did I when I started writing Gimp scripts... Python is a rather simple language to learn... I've seen people lean Python in a couple of days. Some sample Pyhon Gimp scripts: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/